# Funny nesting of links and bold

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

See original post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925223/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-a-random-number-from-0-to-9-in-c/6925263#6925263

---

If I nest the link brackets within the bold tag it doesn't render correctly.

```
**However, you should re-use the random object you create above otherwise [the results won't be very random.]**[2]
```

> **However, you should re-use the random object you create above otherwise [the results won't be very random.]**[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887481/problem-in-generating-random-number)

If I swap the link and bold closing brackets it does.

```
**However, you should re-use the random object you create above otherwise [the results won't be very random.**][2]
```

> **However, you should re-use the random object you create above otherwise [the results won't be very random.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887481/problem-in-generating-random-number)**

I think it should work in the former case, and have undefined results in the latter.

Comment: You do it manually, or by clicking the Hyperlink icon in the editor? (Or pressing CTRL+L) If manually, I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: I first made the hyperlink (clicking the icon), then i added text before it and added the asterisks manually.

Comment: I think it's a bug, becuase it shouldn't matter how i arrived at the formatting that's in my post, the expectations is that the first should work (bold tag and hyperlink tag correctly nested)

Comment: Just tested, doing it all by clicking buttons does it wrong too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The hyperlink tag is made up of two components (three, if you count the link):

1. The text `[text here]`
2. The reference `[1]`
3. The link `[1]: link`

You are inserting the bold syntax in the middle of parts 1 and 2, which is incorrect. The syntax highlighter is doing exactly what is being asked of it: making the text between `**` and `**` bold. The link is not rendering because the asterisks have broken the link syntax.

### Manual steps

```
**However, you should re-use the random object you create above otherwise [the results won't be very random.]**[2]
```

should be:

```
**However, you should re-use the random object you create above otherwise [the results won't be very random.][2]**
```

which renders just fine: **Test [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)**

### With editor buttons

Following your steps (with editor buttons):
`I first made the hyperlink (clicking the icon), then i added text before it and added the asterisks manually`

1. `Link text` => type text.
2. Link text
3. `[Link text][2]` => convert to link.
4. [Link text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)
5. `This is some [Link text][2]` => Add preceding text.
6. This is some [Link text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)
7. `**This is some [Link text][2]**` => highlight text and link and add bold.
8. **This is some [Link text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)**

Comment: +1 great answer, i was having exactly that problem, incorrectly splitting up the link.